# Automatic Differentiation with CoDiPack

Tags: c++, c++11, automatic-differentiation

The following code:

```
#include <codi.hpp>
...
codi::RealForward Gcodi[l];
for (int p = 0; p < l; p++) 
{
     ...
     double a = Gcodi[p];
}
```

gives me the compilation error:

nnBFAD.cpp: In function ‘void OptBF()’:

nnBFAD.cpp:156:25: error: cannot convert ‘codi::RealForward {aka codi::ActiveReal >}’ to ‘double’ in initialization double

```
a = Gcodi[p];
```

Hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official doc [here](https://www.scicomp.uni-kl.de/codi/da/d3d/namespacecodi.html#a1376b659c05fc0567c77f09547cddd08), 
`RealForward`  is a type with an assignment operator overloaded, so you can assign that with a double..

like doing

```
codi::RealForward a = 3.0;
```

the opposite direction is of course not defined,

that is the raeson why you can not convert directly a *codi::RealForward* into a double just by doing:

```
double a = Gcodi[p];
```

but you can call the functions on that, i.e.

```
double a = Gcodi[p].getGradient();
```

---

**UPDATE**:

then you can assign a RealForward object with a double like doing

```
double myDouble{3.3};
RealForward a = myDouble;
```

but is not legal to assign a double directly from the REalForwad:

```
RealForward a = ...;
double myDouble = a; //not valid!
```

other examples

```
RealForward b = a * a; //this is ok because a * a is a double
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a function for that: getValue()

double a = Gcodi[p].getValue();

like stated in: https://www.scicomp.uni-kl.de/codi/d5/dbb/Tutorial1.html